# Android ListFragment creates double list on recreate

Tags: android, view, duplicates, double, fragment

I am trying to implement a basic activity with 2 tabs, each tab containing a list.
Following guides, I have written the following code:

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Notice that setContentView() is not used, because we use the root
        // android.R.id.content as the container for each fragment

        // setup action bar for tabs
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
        actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

        ActionBar.Tab tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab_last_transactions)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<List1Fragment>(
                        this, "list1_fragment", List1Fragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

        tab = actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(R.string.tab_accounts_balance)
                .setTabListener(new TabListener<List2Fragment>(
                        this, "list2_fragment", List2Fragment.class));
        actionBar.addTab(tab);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        new MenuInflater(this).inflate(R.menu.home_menu, menu);
        return (super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu));
    }

}
```

**List1Fragment.java**

```
public class List1Fragment extends ListFragment {

    private static final String[] items = { "Android", "Bluetooth", "Chrome",
            "Docs", "Email", "Facebook", "Google", "Hungary", "Iphone",
            "Korea", "Machintosh", "Nokia", "Orkut", "Picasa", "Singapore",
            "Talk", "Windows", "Youtube" };
    private ArrayList<String> words = null;
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = null;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);


        // Populate list with our static array of titles.
        words = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (String s : items) {
            words.add(s);
        }
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
        setListAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

**list1_fragment.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView android:id="@id/android:list"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="0dp"
              android:background="#00FF00"
              android:layout_weight="1"
              android:drawSelectorOnTop="false"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

The MainActivity is instantiated from a LoginActivity like follows:

**Part of LoginActivity.java**

```
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
```

LoginActivity looks OK.
The first time I start the MainActivity, it's fine, I get the list as expected:

Now I want to see my application life cycle, so I change it to landscape to kill it and recreate it, and it creates an additional list on the top (and again an additional one if I switch back to portrait).
The active one (which scrolls) seems to be the first one that was created.
The additional ones look fix.

Similar result posted in another topic:
[image: Double list]

If I check the (savedInstanceState == null) and set the ListAdapter only when null, it seems to have the desired behaviour (only one list) but there is a "Loading..." on the top of the list.
Adding setListShown(true) throws an exception and exits the program:

**Modified List1_Fragment:**

```
if (savedInstanceState==null)
{
    // Populate list with our static array of titles.
    words = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String s : items) {
        words.add(s);
    }
    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, words);
    setListAdapter(adapter);

}        
else {
    setListShown(true);
}
```

What am I doing wrong?
How can I avoid recreating the list?

(preventing it to regenerate when changing orientation is not an option, I will do this at the end when the application is done, but want to use this feature to test the lifecycle during development, to simulate a kill/restart)

**EDIT:**
Using setListShownNoAnimation instead of setListShown worked...

**EDIT2:**

**TabListener.java**

```
public class TabListener<T extends Fragment> implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment mFragment;
    private final Activity mActivity;
    private final String mTag;
    private final Class<T> mClass;

    /** Constructor used each time a new tab is created.
     * @param activity  The host Activity, used to instantiate the fragment
     * @param tag  The identifier tag for the fragment
     * @param clz  The fragment's Class, used to instantiate the fragment
     */
    public TabListener(Activity activity, String tag, Class<T> clz) {
        mActivity = activity;
        mTag = tag;
        mClass = clz;
    }

    /* The following are each of the ActionBar.TabListener callbacks */

    public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // Check if the fragment is already initialized
        if (mFragment == null) {
            // If not, instantiate and add it to the activity
            mFragment = Fragment.instantiate(mActivity, mClass.getName());
            ft.add(android.R.id.content, mFragment, mTag);
        } else {
            // If it exists, simply attach it in order to show it
            ft.attach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if (mFragment != null) {
            // Detach the fragment, because another one is being attached
            ft.detach(mFragment);
        }
    }

    public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // User selected the already selected tab. Usually do nothing.
    }
}
```

Comment: You're doing something wrong in the `TabListener` class.

Comment: `TabListener` with type parameter?

Comment: I edited my post to add my TabListener, which is a pure copy/paste from the Android docs.
I also added a comment that using setShownNoAnimation(true) worked, but I find it ugly and believe it just hides another issue, maybe in "TabListener", any clue?

Comment: I think the issue is not valid anymore with recent Android versions